# Run .bat file that starts a putty and calls a .sh on remote

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, shell, putty

I wrote a `.bat` file on my computer:

`putty -load <remote-name> -l <user> -pw <password> -m C:\path\shell.txt`

and a `shell.txt` on my computer:

`path/shell.sh`

The `shell.sh` file is on the remote machine and after running the `.bat` file from my computer's cmd, I'd like to run this `.sh` file via putty, but it's not working and I can't find the problem. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Have you checked that it has executable permission by the remote user?

Comment: Yes, doing it manually perfectly works

Comment: have you confirmed that you were able to ssh? can you confirm that the shell script was invoked (and then failed)?

Comment: I don't know what version of `putty` for Windows you were using, but none of the versions I know allows a file name in the run string. Did you omit a redirection `<`?

Comment: Edited: I left out a `-m` parameter in the question

Comment: @ThisIsMyName have you tried plink instead of putty? It is made for this kind of automation.

Comment: A simple rm command runs fine